# child node positioning within compound nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Used cytoscape.js to draw a graph using compound nodes. Need to position the inside node (i.e. child) to specific position of compound node (e.g. left, right, top, bottom, etc.). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is planned for 2.4: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/530