# cytoscape.js layout that allows child positioning within compound (e.g. like dot's rank)

Tags: cytoscape.js, graph-layout

I am trying to use cytoscape to replace my `dot` output and make it interactive (move nodes and compounds, expand/collapse compounds, etc.)
When a graph is first loaded, the user should be presented with a default layout though. However, I am struggling to find a layout/config that supports what `dot` calls `rank`.

In my graph I have compound nodes that represent components.
Components contain other components and/or states, transitions, variables.
Each component can specify `inputs` and `outputs`.
In dot I tried to add some form of flow within the system (`rankdir=LR;`) by positioning the `inputs` on the left (`rank=source;`) and the `outputs` on the right (`rank=sink;`).
Other elements have no `rank` and are hence freely positioned.
I then specified `cluster` subgraphs containing all recursive components.

Now, here is what I have in dot. I hope it explains what I would like to end up with.
[image: dot example that shows an outcome]

First, I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780139/child-node-positioning-within-compound-nodes-in-cytoscape-js), but as far as I understood it's for manual positioning, rather than layouts.

I haven't found a layout that fully supports positioning nodes within the compound.
I looked into using the cytoscape.js-cola layout with the following options:

```
  layout: {
    name: 'cola',
    flow: { axis: 'y', minSeparation: 40 },
    avoidOverlap: true
  }
```

I ended up with this
[image: this is how far I got]
As you can see, there is some flow, but not as nicely as in `dot`.

I tried adding some function for the `alignment` parameter, but as far as I understood I can only specify the absolute coordinates (e.g. `return {'x': 0};`). This basically allows me to align ALL inputs, rather than all inputs of a compound.

Here is a CodePen of my example to play around with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEaOQQ 
In the Javascript you can see the comments of

Answer (score 2):

You could try Klay: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-klay

If any of the existing layouts don't meet your requirements, you can use any algorithm you'd like by [writing a layout extension](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/autoscaffolding).  You could port the exact layout you're using with dot/[graphviz](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/), if you like.

Comment: I hesitated using it since Klayjs is deprecated in favour of [elkjs](https://github.com/OpenKieler/elkjs) (which has no extension yet, but is being actively developed).